# wp_cgi.php File draining server resources

Tags: php, wordpress, cgi, cpu-usage

I have a client on my server who has a wordpress install that is seriously affecting the server resources.

From the logs it seems to be a file in his public html folder called `wp_cgi.php` I've not seen this file in other WP installs before and can't find any reference on the web.

Just wondered if anyone may have a clue what it is - when I look at the code it is some

```
<?php /*FirmaDoBem*/
eval(gzuncompress(base64_decode - followed by encoding.
```

Any ideas - it seems to be constantly running numerous processes and using 59% of ram.

Comment: Take care, it looks like that your site has been hacked, this behaves like a remote shell or web drone. Can happen with a Wordpress setup. Clean up the site and better take care next time, e.g. only make directories and files write-able that need it. Consider doing offline updates even, use version control and track changes.

Comment: Thanks for this - Yeah it doesn't look right at all. I have scanned that entire directory with Clam AV and din't show as a viri. But when I check WHM logs there are maybe 50 or 60 processes showing as running from that script. What should I do - delete that file (or get the client to delete it)?

Comment: If you don't need to further analyse what is going on, you are probably safe to delete it. Take a backup just in case this is needed by some obscure plugin the client has bought or so. But this looks more like that it mimics being a WP file while that's not one. Take care.

Comment: Thanks for the advice _ I killed the processes and now the Ram is at more normal levels for the server. Thanks for your help - Dave

Answer (score 0):

Change `eval` to `echo` and you will probably be able to see what code it runs. Also check the user permissions on the file to see if it may have been uploaded through the web server, and check your web logs to see who calls it and with what parameters.

Comment: Thanks will look into that now